# update column to record if an app script is run for that row or not in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, whatsapp

I am trying to run a google app script with Whatsapp business API to send messages to my customers directly from google sheets. The below app runs fine but every time I run it, it sends the message again and again to all customers irrespective of the same msg being sent to the same customer earlier.

Is there a way, I can add a column and update it automatically to record if the message has been sent to this customer in which case skip to the next (just like in mail merge scripts).

I have the below code and a screenshot of the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecBdW.png)

```js
const WHATSAPP_ACCESS_TOKEN = "**My whatsapp token**";
const WHATSAPP_TEMPLATE_NAME = "**My template name**";
const LANGUAGE_CODE = "en";


const sendMessage_ = ({
  recipient_number,
  customer_name,
  item_name,
  delivery_date,
}) => {
  const apiUrl = "**My api url**";    
  const request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${WHATSAPP_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      messaging_product: "whatsapp",
      type: "template",
      to: recipient_number,
      template: {
        name: WHATSAPP_TEMPLATE_NAME,
        language: { code: LANGUAGE_CODE },
        components: [
          {
            type: "body",
            parameters: [
              {
                type: "text",
                text: customer_name,
              },
              {
                type: "text",
                text: item_name,
              },
              {
                type: "text",
                text: delivery_date,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    }),
  });

  const { error } = JSON.parse(request);
  const status = error ? `Error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}` : `Message sent to ${recipient_number}`;
  Logger.log(status);
};

const getSheetData_ = () => {
  const [header, ...rows] = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const data = []; 
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    const recipient = { };
    header.forEach((title, column) => {
      recipient[title] = row[column];
    });
    data.push(recipient);
  }); 
  return data;
};


const main = () => {
  const data = getSheetData_();
  data.forEach((recipient) => {
      const status = sendMessage_({
        recipient_number: recipient["Phone Number"].replace(/[^\d]/g, ""),
        customer_name: recipient["Customer Name"],
        item_name: recipient["Item Name"],
        delivery_date: recipient["Delivery Date"],
      });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about modifying your script as follows? Please modify `main` as follows.

#### From:

```
const data = getSheetData_();
```

#### To:

```
const temp = getSheetData_();
const { data, ranges } = temp.reduce((o, e, i) => {
  if (e["Sent"] != "sent") {
    o.data.push(e);
    o.ranges.push(`E${i + 2}`);
  }
  return o;
}, { data: [], ranges: [] });
if (ranges.length > 0) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRangeList(ranges).setValue("sent");
}
```

- By this modification, this script checks the column "E" of "Sent". And, the row values without "sent" in column "E" are retrieved as `data`. And, the value of "sent" is put into column "E" of the retrieved rows.

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)